# How can we directly include vue-custom-element in HTML file as a Script?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

How can we directly include **vue-custom-element** in HTML file as a Script?

On the documentation they have mentioned we can directly include [vue-custom-element](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element#direct-include) globaly but I cannot find **vue-custom-element.js** file anywhere.

So How can we implement it directly in HTML file like  this

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://path/to/vue-custom-element.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.4.1/document-register-element.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the project's GitHub page, which contains [vue-custom-element.js](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element/blob/master/src/vue-custom-element.js). The implication is that you host it yourself on your server.

Other third-party CDN sites like [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/vue-custom-element) will host the file as `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-custom-element@3.3.0/dist/vue-custom-element.min.js` (etc), and you could use those at your own risk. There may be other providers, but StackOverflow is not a good place to manage an exhaustive list of third-party resources.

You're already using jsdelivr for the `vue` package, but as with all third party hosting there's no guarantee that the site and file will continue to exist and will not replace your dependency with a nefarious alternative. (The [HTML + SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) option provides a hash commitment that would help ensure you know what you're including, though.)